# engineyard deploy block in replace_bin_path: can't find executable rake error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, engineyard

my application is on rails 3.2.1 ,rake 0.9.2.2, gems 1.8.15 it is working fine on local host.
As i trying to deploy on engineyard am getting the error message in there log file

/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': iconv will be deprecated in the future, use String#encode instead.
/usr/local/ey_resin/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/engineyard-serverside-1.5.28/lib/vendor/thor/lib/thor/shell.rb:10: Use RbConfig instead of obsolete and deprecated Config.
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:219:in`block in replace_bin_path': can't find executable rake (Gem::Exception)
    from /data/emailsending/releases/20120206123528/ey_bundler_binstubs/rake:16:in `<main>'
/usr/local/ey_resin/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/engineyard-serverside-1.5.28/lib/engineyard-serverside/task.rb:62:in`run_on_roles': #, @server=#, @args=[false]> (EY::Serverside::RemoteFailure)
    from /usr/local/ey_resin/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/engineyard-serverside-1.5.28/lib/engineyard-serverside/task.rb:44:in `run'
    from /usr/local/ey_resin/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/engineyard-serverside-1.5.28/lib/engineyard-serverside/deploy.rb:278:in`migrate'
    from /usr/local/ey_resin/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/engineyard-serverside-1.5.28/lib/engineyard-serverside/task.rb:34:in `roles'
    from /usr/local/ey_resin/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/engineyard-serverside-1.5.28/lib/engineyard-serverside/deploy.rb:275:in`migrate'
    from /usr/local/ey_resin/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/engineyard-serverside-1.5.28/lib/engineyard-serverside/deploy.rb:160:in `send'
    from /usr/local/ey_resin/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/engineyard-serverside-1.5.28/lib/engineyard-serverside/deploy.rb:160:in`run_with_callbacks'
    from /usr/local/ey_resin/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/engineyard-serverside-1.5.28/lib/engineyard-serverside/deploy.rb:37:in `cached_deploy'
    from /usr/local/ey_resin/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/engineyard-serverside-1.5.28/lib/engineyard-serverside/deploy.rb:457:in`with_failed_release_cleanup'
     ... 11 levels...
    from /usr/local/ey_resin/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/engineyard-serverside-1.5.28/lib/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:124:in `start'
    from /usr/local/ey_resin/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/engineyard-serverside-1.5.28/bin/engineyard-serverside:10
    from /usr/local/ey_resin/ruby/bin/engineyard-serverside:19:in`load'
    from /usr/local/ey_resin/ruby/bin/engineyard-serverside:19

Comment: did you find a solution for this problem?

Comment: I too am having this problem.  Is there a solution?